# Is there a way to enforce numbers in text mode to have the same style as math environment without putting them between $?

Tags: math-mode, ieeetran, times, computer-modern

I am using the `IEEEtran` document class.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
Here is 123456789 in text mode and 
here is $123456789$ in math mode.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a small, but compilable test document which shows us which font packages you use. Does it maybe have an option for lining figures?

Comment: you can just specify your text font should be used for math digits. By default that is the case for pdflatex, so as always your question would be clearer if you provided an example,

Comment: Do you really want the numbers in text mode to have the same style as in math mode, or do you rather want the numbers in math mode to have the same style as in text mode? If what bugs you is the "Old Style" of the numbers (that is, that the 3, for example, extends below the base line), this can maybe changed depending on the font you use.

Comment: Added a complete latex code using IEEEtran class.

Comment: I get the same style if compiled with lualatex or xelatex https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff68U.png

Comment: Now you changed the font in the picture to one that has no old-style figures, but it is still not the font LaTeX uses by default. It rather looks like Times or the some similar font.

Answer (score 3):

The `IEEEtran` document class employs Times Roman as the default text font and Computer Modern as the default math font. Now, Times Roman and Computer Modern don't mesh all that well, visually speaking.

As @JasperHabicht has already suggested, you ought to consider loading a package such as `newtxmath` to use Times Roman for math-mode material as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[lettersize,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
123456789 text mode

$123456789$ math mode
\end{document}
```